# Android Search box

Tags: android, search, user-interface

I have a screen where there are::
a. Search text field
b. Search button

My database is in MySQL present on some external server.

When user types a text in the text field and hit search button, a list of data from that database should be displayed depending on the text entered in text field.

I want to know should I use "Search box" or a simple textfield for acquiring the "query" text.